# AFHTTPSessionManager Subclass: Post API with body.

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I figured out how to pass params using AFnetworking but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to pass body as part of my API call. Currently this is what I do:

```
    - (void)authenticateUser:(NSString *)username
                password:(NSString *)password
                success:(void (^) (NSString *accessToken))success
                failure:(RequestFailureBlock)failure
{
    NSString *authURL = @"http://someurlforauthentication";
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : username,
                                 @"password" : password };

    [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];




    [self POST:authURL parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){

        NSString *accessToken = responseObject[@"access_token"];

        // Store Access Token
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:APIAuthorizationToken];
        [defaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"Hello %@", accessToken);

        success(accessToken);

    } failure:failure];
}
```

What I need to do is not pass any params and instead pass a body with a json string containing login credentials. Something like this

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// Body

const char bytes[43] = "{\n \"username\": \"max\",\n \"password\": \"pass\"\n}";
request.HTTPBody = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:43];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Using AFJSONRequestSerializer and AFJSONResponseSerializer you can do what you want. Then just use the code you were using to post. The whole process should look like follows:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"test": @"this is a test"};

    [manager POST:@"http://localhost:8080/TestRequest/test" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject description]);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't have a request in my code above. I am subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager. Can you clarify how you would add this to the code I have in my post?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps. The code above takes a json input and returns a json output.

Comment: I perceive this answer to not fully answer the question.  Unless the title changed after this post you have parameters, but no body.  No HTTPBody (e.g. Swift 2.3 -          let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url); ...  request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(someDict as AnyObject, options: .PrettyPrinted);).  I see the parameters being loaded on the URL endpoint, but no HTTPBody.  Am I wrong and not seeing the body?